# Как выводить объекты Queryset'а по одному?

Tags: html, python, ajax, django

Идея такая: фильтром выбрать из базы несколько элементов (вопросов к тесту). Далее надо выводить эти элементы по одному. Сначала выводим первый вопрос теста, когда пользователь ответил - второй, и так далее. И чтобы это происходило без обновления страницы. Не могу понять как это реализовать.
Как отслеживать какой вопрос выведен и как выбирать следующий, после ответа. Вроде как нужен ajax. Если да, то что писать во вью. И в запросе?

```
def index(request, course_id, test_task_id):
    test = Test_task.objects.get(id = test_task_id)
    test_question_list = Test_question.objects.filter(test_task = test_task_id)
    for t in test_question:
        answer_test_list = Answer_test.objects.filter(test_question = t.id)
   if request.user.is_authenticated():
        if request.method == "POST" and request.is_ajax():
         #что делать если на вопрос ответили
        else:
         #как вывести первый вопрос
            context = {'test': test,'test_question' : test_question, 'answer_test' : answer_test, 'course_id':course_id}
            return render(request, 'test_task/test_task.html', context)
else:
    return redirect("user_profile:login_view")
```

Все вопросы выводятся так:

```
    <h3>Тест. {{ test.name_test }}</h3>
    <div class="question-panel">
        {% for t in test_question %}
        <div class="question_text" data-num="{{t.id}}">
            {{t.question_text|linebreaksbr}}
        </div>
        <div class="list-group"><div>
            {% for answer in answer_test %}
             <a id="v_1" class="list-group-item questvariant" data-num="{{answer.id}}"> {{ answer.answer }}</a>
            {% endfor %}
        </div></div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Пыталась как-то так делать запрос:

```
$(" .questvariant").click( function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    var quest_id = $(".question_text").data("num");
    var var_id = $(this).data("num");
    var data = {
        'quest_id' : quest_id,
        'var_id' : var_id,
    };
     alert(data);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/test/1/1/",
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){

        }
   });
});
```

Comment: Передавайте в ответе id или url, по которому можно запросить следующий вопрос {'test': test, ... , 'next': next_question}.

Comment: @Chikiro но в таком случае будет переход на другую страницу. а этого не нужно делать.

Comment: Вы сами решаете в js, делать переход на другую страницу, или какие-то данные контент на текущую.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы знать, какой вопрос должен быть следующим - нужно знать какой текущий. Рекомендуется использовать смещение по заранее отсортированному queryset, т.е. например

```
Test_question.objects.all().order_by('id')[offset:] # Вместо id можно поставить поле position для солртировки по порядку
```

Но тут нужно проверять, чтобы offset не выходил за границы

Также можно указывать в модели, какой вопрос будет следущим/предыдущим, добавив поля

```
class TestQuestion(models.Model):
    ....
    next = models.OneToOneField('TestQuestion', related_name='prev', blank=True, null=True)
```

В этом случае, можно узнать id следущего вопроса, обратившись к старому

Вообще много вариантов решения этого вопроса существует... )

Про AJAX - лучше отправлять на урл типа /test/(?P\d+) с GET/POST параметром ответа и возвращать блок, который должен заменить блок прошлого вопроса

Answer (score 0):

вообще, если нет какой-то зависимости между следующим вопросом и предыдущим, а так же нет какой-то особой секретности в этих вопросах, ты можешь банально вывести все вопросы заранее, но скрыв их на странице, и потом с помощью javascript показывать только тот вопрос какой тебе нужен на данный момент.